# SetInterval loop until found element

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, do-while

Hey all I am not getting the results I am looking for with this javascript. When i execute it in IE, this is what it has in the console:

> Starting
>
> at Step 2
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> Step 1 Exists!
>
> etc....

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
javascript: (function () {
    var t = "34637",
    a = "fhh",
    l = "Rule",
    i = "baywatch",
    o = "NMN",
    n = "C",
    s = "US",
    d = "US",
    q = "M",
    m = "IA",
    p = "05/22/1994",
    y = "DL",
    z = "Ztghy663";
    console.log("Starting");
    var c = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('[title="Submit a Search"]').length) {
                console.log("Step 1 Exists!");
                clearInterval(c);
                $('[title="Submit a Search"]').click();
            }
        }, 100);
    console.log("at Step 2");
    c = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Step 2!");
        if ($('[data-test-id="201707241746357527497-Label"]').length) {
            console.log("Step 2 Exists!");
            clearInterval(c);

            t = prompt("Please enter the number:", "");
            $('[data-test-id="2017072417423205261024660"]').val = t; /*Sets the Number textbox*/
            console.log("at Step 3");
        }
    }, 100);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 title="Submit a Search"> </h1>
```

I'm not really sure about this. My thought was that it would start and not leave that loop until it finds it. It clicks on the title Submit a Search so I know that's working but as you see above it keeps looping even though its found...

I'm sure I am just looking over something easy but at this moment I cant find anything wrong with the code...

Comment: I have added an answer with explanation, do let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that while you store the interval id in this line, which is defined for step 1

```
var c = setInterval(function () {
```

You override it with this line, which you define it for step 2

```
c = setInterval(function () {
```

So, it tries to clear the interval of the step 2 function, inside the step1 method, hence step1 setInterval is not cleared.

YOu just need to store both the intervals in separate variables, so that you can clear both.

Updated working code.

```js
javascript: (function () {
    var t = "34637",
    a = "fhh",
    l = "Rule",
    i = "baywatch",
    o = "NMN",
    n = "C",
    s = "US",
    d = "US",
    q = "M",
    m = "IA",
    p = "05/22/1994",
    y = "DL",
    z = "Ztghy663";
    console.log("Starting");
    var c1 = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('[title="Submit a Search"]').length) {
                console.log("Step 1 Exists!");
                clearInterval(c1);
                $('[title="Submit a Search"]').click();
            }
        }, 100);
    console.log("at Step 2");
    var c2 = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Step 2!");
        if ($('[data-test-id="201707241746357527497-Label"]').length) {
            console.log("Step 2 Exists!");
            clearInterval(c2);

            t = prompt("Please enter the number:", "");
            $('[data-test-id="2017072417423205261024660"]').val = t; /*Sets the Number textbox*/
            console.log("at Step 3");
        }
    }, 100);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 title="Submit a Search"> </h1>
<h2 data-test-id="201707241746357527497-Label"> </h2>
```